# To parse the query string not working

Tags: node.js

Im self-educating Node.js. I have created two simple HTML files (summer.html and winter.html) and noded the JS on node.js. I went on localhost:5354/summer.html (and winter.html). Nothing is showing up and I got an error message

```
This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I have tested other lessons and was able to display results on localhost:5354/ but this one doesnt work. What did I do wrong?

JS

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var filename = "." + q.pathname;
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            return res.end("404 Not Found");
        }
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        return res.end();
    });
}).listen(5343);
```

Comment: you need to handle routing in your server.js (or main.js, the main back-end js file) or have the html files placed related to the index.html

Comment: You're listening port 5343, but in browser using 5354.

Comment: Usually a simple port is used, 3000 for example.

Comment: My bad, it was actually 5354 instead of 5343! What a bonehead! I rechecked netstat again and showed 5354. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit this URL
localhost:5343/summer.html

Because, You listen in 5343 PORT. But you hit 5354 Port